# Webmail Interface for Direct Access to Maildir Directory (No IMAP, POP3 on Purpose)

Tags: email, maildir

I am using a service providers that allows me to forward email to a shell account.  I work/play in a lot of environments where I cannot SSH into the host a lot of the time, and I want to separate out the error and log emails from automated services to a special account, and wanted to play around with some email filtering stuff.  They plop a Maildir directly right into my `~/home/` profile.  Is there a possibility I can find a webmail client that will give me a "pretty little interface" that accesses the dir **directly** instead of setting up an IMAP/POP3 server?  It is a shared host, so that is out of the question.  If not, no big deal.  I was considering moving to another filter to filter it out of the shell anyway.

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I am familiar with SquirrelMail and Roundcube, but I cannot figure out the latter (which I preferred) can be configured without an IMAP/POP3 server, but I doubt it.